# Generic ways to invoke syscalls from the shell

Tags: perl, shell, system-calls

I like to call `truncate(const char *path, off_t length)` (see [`man 2 truncate`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate)) directly from the command line or in shell script.

I guess I could embed a C program and then compile, run, and remove it.

Another short alternative is using `perl -e "truncate($file,$length)"`.

**Questions:**

Is `perl -e "syscall(params...)"` the most common pattern to invoke syscalls? How well does it cover other syscalls?

Is there another common way to invoke Linux/BSD syscalls from the shell?
For instance, using a command like `syscall "truncate($file,$length)"`?

Comment: Or `python`, or `ruby`, or `lua`, or just about any other interpreted language which exposes similar functionality.

Comment: What particular actions do you want to achieve?

Comment: You can call `truncate(2)` from shell via `truncate(1)` command. It will take care of the width of the length argument etc. and is more portable than perl `syscall NUMBER, LIST`. In general, you do not need to invoke syscalls directly from shell.

Comment: @Сухой27: in particular, I wanted to truncate a file. However, since there are other missing features on the shell, such as generic way of getting the current time in ms or µs, I though about using BSD/Linux syscalls for that purpose, e.g., calling `gettimeofday(2)`.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: `truncate(1)` is not available on the my Mac. That is why I was looking for a generic solution in the first place.

Comment: Skip syscall if you're looking for generic solutions. Check http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html for current us/ms.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I tried to summarize the lessons learned in a summarizing answer -- hoping the question will not be closed as too broad ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for all comments and suggestions. I conclude the following answers to my questions:

1. Some scripting languages, e.g., `perl`, may provide functions that resemble or wrap some of the useful syscalls, i.e., those that would make sense calling from the shell.
2. However, there is no 1:1 mapping of scripting APIs and syscalls and no "common pattern" or tool to invoke many different types of syscalls from the shell.

Moreover, a generic solution for a specific problem should not focus on syscalls in the first place, but rather use a generic language or library from the beginning. For instance, for file truncation this may actually be perl, using `perl -e "truncate($file,$length)"`.